# Ubuntu 20.04 Bluetooth "Connection to the device failed"

Tags: bluetooth

This is to my bluetooth headphone.

[image: screen1]

Then I click on "Connect", and after a few seconds, I get this message:

[image: screen2]

"Connection to the device failed"

The strange thing is, this has worked previously.
There might have been updates in between but I'm not exactly sure.

Also, I was dual booting Windows before, and there Bluetooth with the same headphone works just fine. I recheck by booting in again to Windows, and it still works, but then booting back to Linux, and it does not work.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working) sounds related, because some people also report dual boots with Windows. However, the suggestion with reloading `btusb` (or maybe also `btintel`) did not help.

I had some previous issues with wifi + dual booting with Windows before. I did sth and it solved it, but I forgot what I was. I remember that to permanently get rid of this, I was supposed to disable the Windows "Fast Boot" feature. But there was another workaround to make it working. Related questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254608/the-wifi-is-disabled-when-i-start-with-windows-and-then-go-back-to-ubuntu-a-res) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285569/wifi-doesnt-want-to-connect-until-restart-ubuntu-20-04), but I had found some other question/website with more information, but I don't find it anymore.

Anyway, I disabled the "Fast Boot" feature in Windows, and the wifi is working all the time. I did not had any issues anymore.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of digging I was able to sove this issue for myself which involved connecting a bluetooth audio device. For me it was specifically a JBL Charge4.

The solution was to install the pulseaudio Bluetooth module and restart it:

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

Then when I try to pair I no longer get the message and it works.

Comment: Yessir! Worked for my LG HBS700 headset!

Answer (score 1):

I had "Connection to the device failed" problem - helped to unpair (delete) the headphones and pair (add) them again